# Proving trigonometric inequality.

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

I am trying to prove that

$$f(x)=\dfrac{3-\dfrac{\cos x}{\cos(\frac{x}{3})}}{x^2}$$
for  $ x \in \left(0 , \frac{{\pi}}{2} \right)$ $f(x)$ is strictly decreasing function for  $ x \in \left(0 , \frac{{\pi}}{2} \right)$

By letting $x=3t$ for $t \in (0,\frac{\pi}{6})$ we get

\begin{align*}
 9f(x)=g(t)=\dfrac{3 \cos t-\cos(3t)}{t^2\cos t}
\end{align*}
A simple computation shows that one has
$$t^3\cos^2t\cdot g'(t)=3t\cos(t)\sin(3t)+2\cos(t)\cos(3t)-t \sin(t) \cos(3t)-6\cos^2(t)=h(t)$$
We will show that $h(t)<0$ for any $t \in \left(0 , \frac{{\pi}}{6} \right)$, or equivalently

$$3t\cos(t)\sin(3t)+2\cos(t)\cos(3t)-t\sin(t)\cos(3t)-6\cos^2(t)<0$$

From here I don't know how to proceed. Any help to prove the inequality will be much appreciated!

Comment: FYI: The left-hand side happens to simplify to $$4 \cos^2t (\cos2 t + t \sin2 t-2)$$

Comment: @Blue this form is quite helpful in solving it. For $0 \leq t \leq {\pi/6}$, max value of $t sin2t$ is $\pi/12$. and so the expression will be negative.

Comment: @MathLover: I didn't want to give *everything* away. :)

Comment: I won't get into a roll-back battle with you, but I will note that it's a good idea to have a title that reflects the point of the question as accurately as possible. An informative title helps readers scanning the Questions list know whether to bother clicking into an item; contrariwise, a generic title makes life difficult for site-searchers who may get confronted with what could be *dozens* of results unhelpfully named "Prove trigonometric inequality". (Also, highlighting the specific part of the question that needs attention can help readers who otherwise face a wall of text.)

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x)=\frac{3-\frac{\cos (x)}{\cos \left(\frac{x}{3}\right)}}{x^2}$$
$$f'(x)=\frac{4 \left(x \sin \left(\frac{2 x}{3}\right)+3 \cos \left(\frac{2 x}{3}\right)-6\right)}{3 x^3}$$
As the denominator is positive on $[0,\pi/2]$ let's consider the numerator.

We have on  $[0,\pi/2]$ that

$$x \sin \left(\frac{2 x}{3}\right)+3 \cos \left(\frac{2 x}{3}\right)-6<\frac{\pi}{2}+3-6<0$$
Therefore $f'(x)<0$ on the given interval, thus the function is strictly decreasing.